# How send orderid/itemno to paypal and get back in PayPal Express Checkout API

Tags: php, paypal

How send orderid/itemno to paypal and get back to my site. I want to update that orderid is purchased

What is the purpose of Token ID or CORRELATION ID or TRANSACTIONID?

API works fine

**Got back result**

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-2R626219M62454427
    [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-11-04T09:38:47Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 2441b978c048b
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 104.0
    [BUILD] => 8334781
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 7JM13596VP514480B
    [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [ORDERTIME] => 2013-11-04T09:38:46Z
    [AMT] => 1.00
    [FEEAMT] => 0.33
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [REASONCODE] => None
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
    [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 7JM13596VP514480B
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2013-11-04T09:38:46Z
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 1.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 0.33
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => YYA4BXSJ722PJ
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
)
```

Answer (score 1):

CorrelationID: Internal identifier used by PayPal to look up the exact API request in logs.
TransactionID: self-explanatory; this is the transactionID for the created transaction.
Token: a temporary token used to redirect the buyer to the PayPal website with.

What you probably want is the `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM` parameter. You can specify `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM` in your initial `SetExpressCheckout` API call. Then when `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` is called, this value is returned in the response.

More details are in the [SetExpressCheckout API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).

Comment: But I want to know how to send order id and get back?

Comment: Exactly. In your SetExpressCheckout call, specify PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=YourOrderIsGoesHere, and then it'll be returned to you in both the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response and following IPN message (if you're using IPN).

Comment: How can i Send order id?

Comment: I send my order id in SetExpressCheckout  as 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'=>'101', but i didnt get return back

Comment: Do you know of anything similar using the REST API (not classic)?  I don't see anywhere to stash my internal transaction_id when creating a new payment. (I'm using paypal php sdk)